# How to use multiline <<EOF in bash with assigning output to variable?

Tags: bash, eof

Let's say that I have a code like:

```bash
python <<EOF
print("abc")
EOF
```

and I want to assign output to bash variable. Something like:

```bash
VAR=$(python -c 'print("abc")')
```

Of course real python code is more complicated than `print(abc)` and one-liner can't be used here

So the qestion is how to assign output of first example to variable?

I tried some variations of

```bash
VAR=$(python <<EOF
print("abc")
EOF )

VAR=$(python) <<EOF
print("abc")
EOF
```

But this syntax is not correct

Comment: Place the closing `)` after the line or below the closing `EOF`, on a side note you can quote the opening `EOF` e.g. `'EOF'` so special characters from the shell will not be expanded/interpeted

Comment: See `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*Here\ Documents' man bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it adding the closing parenthesis in a new line. This works for me:

```
VAR=$(python <<EOF
print("abc")
EOF
)
```

Hope it helps